# Thermodynamic planks temperature

Tags: thermodynamics

There is a limit of temperature that is about $0$ K = $-273.15$ $^\circ$C. Is there any maximum limit?

Comment: *planks temperature* Do you mean Planck?

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Not really. (I need 30 characters)

Comment: Ever heard of the Hagedorn temperature?